# Class not found with maven JDBC mysql

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

I'm getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jdbc.driver}
```

whilst trying to set up a netbeans maven project which can switch between MySQL and hsql by activating different profiles. It gets connection data from a database.properties file, and is throwing this error when I try and run it.

POM profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>mysql</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <mysql.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</mysql.url>
            <mysql.username>SA</mysql.username>
            <mysql.password></mysql.password>
            <mysql.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</mysql.driver>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

database.properties:

```
jdbc.url=${jdbc.url}
jdbc.username=${jdbc.username}
jdbc.password=${jdbc.password}
jdbc.driver=${jdbc.driver}
```

I have "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar" set up as a dependancy, but it doesnt seem to like my driver. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like the substitution in database.properties hasn't been done

Comment: MySQL Connector/J 5.1.6 is pretty old, you might want to use a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to have the same properties (keys) in each profile, and should be referenced in the file (in order to be replaced).

```
<properties>
            <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</db.url>
            <db.username>SA</db.username>
            <db.password></db.password>
            <db.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
</properties>
```

An then

```
jdbc.url=${db.url}
jdbc.username=${db.username}
jdbc.password=${db.password}
jdbc.driver=${db.driver}
```

Last but not least you need to activate the filtering of the propery file, which must be somewhere in the src/main/resources (of whatever path in the resources folder it is).

Adding in your pom something like this

```
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for details.

hope that helps

Comment: Hi, I tried this but unfortunately made no difference, apparently I already had filtering on and my resource directory referenced using tags build->resources->resource

Comment: do an mvn clean package and can you check your target folder and see what happens on the property file. Where do you place the property file (the path?) src/main/resources/? src/main/resources/META-INF/ ? somewhere else

Comment: I did a clean install before and it didnt work, but doing another one now it has worked I think? Now I am getting the error `Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure` Do I have to set up a mysql db externally to get this to work or is this a different problem entirely?

Comment: 1. try to execute the maven commands outside your IDE, I think that you are getting weird behavior due to ubnormal executions of Maven ( are you using eclipse?) 2. The Database that you point from your properties, is it running?Have you test it with a GUI client, can you connect? If not how do you expect the driver /web app to do it?

Comment: Is there any way for me to save to file/memory to test without deploying a server? For example in hsql you can simply set the url as `<jdbc.url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB</jdbc.url>`

Comment: In your question you indicate that you already have an hsql profile. So activate the profile while building 'mvn clean install -P<name of the hsdb profile> . Now are you running on a container, you need to make sure the container runs an instance of your in memory db, or you run it on your own. But this is a different question than the original right? I think the property file, replacement is done right :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing ${jdbc.driver} with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: this gives the error `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ${jdbc.url}`